# Could not install package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 24.2.1'. ... targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0'

Tags: xamarin.android

i tried to update nuget packages in xamarin android but i get this error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Could not install package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 24.2.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

in android manifest i have this `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="24" />`

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You're desired package has dependencies to Android 6 (API 23). Your minSdkVersion is to high, change it to `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" />`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using Android API version 23 and **Compat version 24.2.1** was supported for API versions greater than 23. I installed **API version 24** or you can say **Android Version 7.0** then it was successfully installed. 
***make sure*** to set the target version of your app to the latest android version installed that is above API version 23. 
***make sure*** to run visual studio as administrator and then install the package in some cases it requires to have admin privileges to read or replace the packages.